# Access to a file located in a nested folder in the application's bundle

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, widget

I'm working on an iOS widget. I have a barcode image stored here in the application bundle:

```
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6FXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX97/tmp/ReactNative/B93FF931-8A80-48F1-8669-E9A1B4476A35.jpg
```

I want to render it in my widget. I have this view for rendering the barcode UI:

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct BarcodeView: View {
    var barcode: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, content: {
            if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "B93FF931-8A80-48F1-8669-E9A1B4476A35", ofType: "jpg"),
               let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path) {
                Image(uiImage: image)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
            }
            Spacer()
            Text(barcode)
                .font(.subheadline)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
        })
    }
}
```

It does not show the image. The image file is definitely there though. I confirmed it by downloading the app's container.

I tried different variations like the below ones for the bundle path, but none of them worked. I tried all of them with and without a leading slash and with and with the extension in the path.

```swift
Bundle.main.path(forResource: "B93FF931-8A80-48F1-8669-E9A1B4476A35", ofType: "jpg")
Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ReactNative/B93FF931-8A80-48F1-8669-E9A1B4476A35", ofType: "jpg")
Bundle.main.path(forResource: "tmp/ReactNative/B93FF931-8A80-48F1-8669-E9A1B4476A35", ofType: "jpg")
Bundle.main.path(forResource: "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6FCE3256-31DD-465A-A336-6D3F2D2C6697/tmp/ReactNative/B93FF931-8A80-48F1-8669-E9A1B4476A35", ofType: "jpg")
```

I'm a React native dev so I might have been missing something simple here. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Use [Bundle.path(forResource:ofType:inDirectory:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1409670-path)

Comment: @dalton_c I tried this, but I'm getting the same result: `if let path = Bundle.path(forResource: "B93FF931-8A80-48F1-8669-E9A1B4476A35", ofType: "jpg", inDirectory: "tmp/ReactNative")`

Answer (score 0):

First option should work fine:

```swift
Bundle.main.path(forResource: "B93FF931-8A80-48F1-8669-E9A1B4476A35", 
ofType: "jpg")
```

I think the issue is with file's target membership, while you are building a widget your project must have multiple targets in it and you need to make sure that the file is available for your widget.

[image]